# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

Tags: activerecord, shopify

I am using rails 2.3.4, rubygems 1.3.6, activerecord 3.1.0, windows 7 home basic

Here's my code:

```
def items
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)
    @products.each do |a| 
    begin
    @shop = Product.new(:title => a.title , :shop_id => a.id, :product_type => a.product_type)
    @shop.save
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
            redirect_to :action => "display_items"
        end
    end
    @shop_items =Product.find(:all)
    if session[:user_id]
            @log = "Welcome Administrator!"
            @logout="logout"
        else
            @log = "Admin Log in"
            @logout=""
        end

end
```

I'm having the error "uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique" when trying to save the data fed by the API. Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you use ActiveRecord 3.1 with Rails 2.3.4. Though it's possible to use that, it is not recommended.

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` is only available with versions 3.0 or higher. I am not sure if activerecord modules are initialized correctly with your version of Rails.

Comment: well i'm trying to use rails 2 than rails 3 because that's what's required to me. what do you suggest i can do?

Comment: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry 'Baby Ruth-49696852' for key 'uni_products': INSERT INTO `products` (`product_type`, `title`, `shop_id`) VALUES('Food', 'Baby Ruth', 49696852) ----> THIS IS THE ERROR WHEN THE EXCEPTION IS TRIGGERED.

Comment: actually i'm not really familiar of the console but the above error is what's triggered in the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

That error is returned when ActiveRecord tries to save a duplicate when the index says values need to be unique. In your case, the value `Baby Ruth-49696852` is a duplication, and violates the `uni_products` key, which is set to be unique.

Either make the column not unique, or stop trying to save duplicate records. Did you create your database indexes in your migrations? Is there a `:unique => true` on any of the columns in your migrations?